# Computing p and q from private key

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, factoring, cryptography

We are given n (public modulus) where $n=pq$ and $e$ (encryption exponent) using RSA. Then I was able to crack the private key $d$, using Wieners attack. So now, I have $(n,e,d)$. My question: is there a way to calculate p and q from this information? If so, any links and explanation would be much appreciated!

Comment: I assume this is RSA?  You should write that in your question.

Answer (score 2):

If it is valid RSA, then $ L = ed-1$ is a multiple of the Carmichael function $\lambda(n) = \mathrm{lcm}(p-1, q-1)$.

In the solutions to exercise 18.12 (ii) from J. v. zur Gathen, J. Gerhard, Modern computer algebra [Modern computer algebra](http://math-www.uni-paderborn.de/mca/), 2nd ed. (2003),  you find **ALGORITHM 18.16 Special integer factorization**. This randomized algorithm computes the set of prime divisors of an squarefree odd integer $N \ge 3$, given a multiple $L \in \mathbb{N}$ of $\lambda(N).$

You can get the solution manual to selected exercises from the
[authors site](http://www-math.uni-paderborn.de/mca/solutions.ps.gz), it includes the pseudo code for Alg. 18.16.

If you are using CRT-RSA you can recover p,q from n,e,dp (dp is CRT exponent of p) by an algorithm from S. Maitra, S. Sarkar: Polynomial-Time Equivalence of Computing the CRT-RSA Secret Key(s) and Factoring (http://eprint.iacr.org/2009/062)

**Edit:** As Jyrki Lahtonen suggested, here are the main ideas from MCA Algorithm 18.16:

Write $L=2^k m, k \ge 1$ with odd $m$. Choose a random $a \in [2,N-2]$. If $\gcd(a,N) \ne 1 $ you have found a factor by accident. Otherwise compute $b_0=a^m \pmod N$. If $b_0=1 \pmod N$, choose another $a$. Otherwise compute $b_{i+1} = b_i^2 \pmod N$ for $i=0\dots k$. Compute $g=\gcd(b_j,N)$ where $j$ is maximum index with $b_j\ne 1 \pmod N$. If $g\ne 1$ and $g \ne N$ it is a non-trivial factor, otherwise choose another $a$.

Comment: It wouldn't IMVHO hurt to describe the basic idea here. I happen to have a copy of v.z.Gathen & Gerhard on my shelf, so I could look it up. AFAICT the idea is to find a non-trivial square root of $1$ modulo $n$ much like in Rabin-Miller except that with the extra bit about Carmichael function available we can rule out the possibility of $a^L\not\equiv 1\pmod n.$ Anyway, write $L=2^mL'$ with $L'$ odd, and start squaring mod $n$ number of the form $a^{L'}$ with random $a$. Repeat as necessary. BTW My edition (2003 I think) does not have Algorithm 18.16 - stops at 18.15 :-)

Comment: @Jyrki_Lahtonen: Yes, Algorithm 18.16 is only in the solutions text http://www-math.uni-paderborn.de/mca/solutions.ps.gz on page 80f. But it is much easier to implement (9 stages of pseudo code) than to describe (roughly a complete page). I have done it for my Pascal library (without the need to completely understand the math).

Answer (score 2):

If the public exponent $e$ was calculated as $e=d^{-1}\mod{\phi(n)}$ you probably simply found secret exponent $d$ as denominator of fraction $\frac{k}{d}$, which is the one of convergents for contuned fraction $\frac{e}{n}$ (This is simplified Wiener's attack assuming use of Euler's totient function when generating inverse exponent). In this case use the probabilistic algorithm mentioned in the answer above. The underlying mathematics of it was described in [A Further Weakness In The Common Modulus Protocol For The Rsa Cryptoalgorithm](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0161-118491859060) article.

In case of using Carmichael function $\lambda(n)$ to calculate public exponent, i assume you had to follow the complete algirthm which Wiener showed in his article [Cryptanalysis of Short RSA Secret Exponents](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~whli/lecture-crypto-pb/materials/cryptanalysis%20of%20short%20RSA%20secret%20exponents.pdf). If so, you do not need the above probabilistic algorithm, because following the complete Wiener's algorithm you had to calculate both intermediate guess of $\frac {p+q} {2}=a$ and guess of $\frac {p-q} {2}=b$. Having the latter two you can get factors of $n$ by calculating: $q=a-b$ and $q=a+b$. In other words Wiener's attack on RSA also gives factorization. See the formulas (31) and (32) in Wiener's article and his example.